# Could MongoDB send multiply update commands at once?

Tags: mongodb

In my project, I have to update documents in MongoDB many times. I find MongoDB support insert a lot of documents with `insert_many` use a single command, but I can't use `update_many` to update a lot at once, they have difference condition. I have to update them one by one.

With `insert_many`, I can insert more than 7000 documents per second. At the same environment, there are only about 1500 documents could be updated per second. It just seems inefficient to send thousands of commands when one will do.

Is it possible to send multiple update commands to MongoDB server at once?

---

Thanks for your explain @Blakes Seven,  I have rewritten my program with `Bulk` and update documents with "unordered" operation. There is the speed report on my test environment.

- 1 thread: 12655 doc/s     cpu: 150 - 200%
- 2 threads: 19005 doc/s     cpu:  200 - 300%
- 3 threads: 24433 doc/s     cpu:  300 - 400%
- 4 threads: 28957 doc/s     cpu:  400 - 500%
- 5 threads: 35586 doc/s     cpu:  500 - 600%
- 6 threads: 32942 doc/s     cpu:  600+%

On my test environment, `test program` and `MongoDB server` running on the same machine,  It seems not perfect for  multiple threads. The `CPU usage` of MongoDB when run the program with a single thread, It was between 150% and 200%. MongoDB executed the operations in parallel exactly, seems have a limit of the threads with a client connect.

Anyway, a single thread is enough for me, besides, fewer thread has higher efficiency.

Another report on the online environment that client and server running on a different machine:

- 1 thread: 14719 doc/s
- 2 threads: 26837 doc/s
- 3 threads: 34908 doc/s
- 4 threads: 46151 doc/s
- 5 threads: 47842 doc/s
- 6 threads: 52522 doc/s

Comment: check [mongo bulk operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/)

Comment: Which language and driver? They all basically have the same methods avaiilable. See ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)

Comment: Thank you very much @yogesh and @Blakes Seven, I used `pymongo` first, now I use `mongo_c_driver` to instead, I can use multiply thread to improve the performance of update.  I'm very ashamed of miss the `bulk` in the MongoDB document. It works much faster than before, thank you.

Comment: If you "read everything" about "Bulk" ( and I have posted responses that say this many times myself ) then you would find that "unordered" operations will execute on the server in "parallel" therefore in multiple threads anyway. Calls only send to the server on `.execute()` so there is no specific advantage in breaking other operations into "threads" since they don't call the server anyway and are basically instantaneous. Of course you can always have multiple"bulk" threads working to "send" in parallel. But that is another question. Write some code first, then ask that one.

Comment: Thanks for your explain @Blakes Seven, I can't write my report in commends, so I write at `question`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with

```
db.collection.findAndModify()
```

Please go through documentation :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: The question was about doing updates to many documents in bulk, findAndModify "modifies and returns a single document."